# Exporting Prisma Relational Database to .csv in its entirety (including relations)

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I created a postgresql database using prisma and it includes several many-to-many relations. I am trying to export the root table (that includes all the relations) as a single .csv with the data in the relations represented as well. The issue is that when I try and export I can't find a way to include the relation information as well. Similar to the example below:

```
model thing {
  relationOne relations[]
  relationTwo relations[]

  statOne Int
  statTwo Int
}

model relationOne {
  assignedThing thing[]

  statOne String
  statTwo String
}

model relationTwo {
  assignedThing thing[]

  statOne String
  statTwo String
}
```

The idea would be to export a .csv of the thing table that included the statOne/statTwo information in each relation. Is this possible?

This is the SQL that was generated by pgadmin to create the .csv file:

```
copy public.model (id, movement, toughness, save, wounds, leadership, \"objectiveControl\", \"invulnerableSave\", \"factionKeywords\", keywords, \"modelName\", \"unitAssignedId\", points, \"degradeText\") TO '/home/mnemonicds/Documents/testExport' DELIMITER ',' CSV QUOTE '\"' ESCAPE '''';""
```

Comment: Can you please share the query that you are invoking to export the data?

Comment: I believe this is it (adding to the post), although I used pgadmin 4 to generate it - I'm not particularly competent with SQL.